# what is the Fourier cosine transform of $e^{-ax}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

What is the Fourier cosine transform of $e^{-ax}$

I got

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(kx)e^{-ax}dx = \frac{e^{-ax}(k\sin(kx) -\cos(kx))} {a^{2}+k^{2}}\Bigr|_{0}^{\infty}
$$

But how do you continue from here?

Comment: Hint! Write $\cos{kx}=\frac{1}{2}\big( e^{kx}+e^{-kx} \big)$.

Comment: @krvolok you might want to re-think that hint.

Comment: Oops! Hint! Correct my hint and go on :)

Answer (score 1):

The expression you obtained is incorrect. It is missing a factor of $a$ in front of the cosine term.

Assume $a > 0$. (Otherwise the integral does not converge.)
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(k x)e^{-ax}\,dx &= Re \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{i k x}e^{-ax}\,dx\\
&= Re \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(i k - a)x}\,dx\\
&= Re\; \frac{e^{(i k - a)x}}{i k - a}\; \Bigr|_{0}^{\infty}
\end{align}
Since $a>0$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{(i k - a)x}$ is zero, and we are left with:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(k x)e^{-ax}\,dx \;=\; Re\; \frac{-1}{i k - a} \;=\;
\frac{a}{a^2 + k^2}
$$

As weird as it may sound for a question which is evidently purely-mathematical, one way to catch an error such as the missing $a$ above is by dimensional analysis. Imagine that the units of $x$ are length. Then for consistency, $a$ and $k$ must have units of inverse length. That means you can't  add or subtract two terms like $k \sin(k x)$ and $\cos(kx)$, since they have different units. (One has units of inverse length, the other is dimensionless.) If you arrive at such an expression, then there must have been a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Note that [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=real+part+of+e%5E((ik-a)x)%2F(ik-a)) confirms the only error is the missing $a$, so I'm not really following you on the whole dimensional analysis part.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You are right that the missing $a$ was the only error. My point was just that dimensional analysis can be used to catch simple errors like that even for purely-mathematical problems with no obvious units assigned.

Answer (score -1):

Observe that if $a>0$ then
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{-ax}(k\sin(kx) -\cos(kx))=0.
$$

Answer (score -1):

I think it makes sense to chose $f(x) = e^{-a|x|}$ and $a>0$ otherwise the integral does not make any sense.

$$\mathcal{F}_{\cos}(f)(k) =\int_{\Bbb R}\cos(kx)e^{-a|x|}dx \\= 2\int_{\Bbb R}\cos(kx)e^{-ax}dx =2\frac{e^{-ax}(k\sin(kx) -\cos(kx))} {a^{2}+k^{2}}\Bigr|_{0}^{\infty} =\frac{1}{a^2+k^2}$$
Given that $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{-ax}(k\sin(kx) -\cos(kx))=0.$$